# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCHibernate/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, configuration, http-status-code-404

I have been trying to work my Spring Hibernate Web Sample in Eclipse in Tomcat. Unfortunately, I get the following warning:

> WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found
>   for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCHibernate/] in DispatcherServlet
>   with name 'appServlet'

What I need to do for the warning ? As far as I see , I could not see an exact solution for that. I will be appreciated if you can help me.

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee               http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and   Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
     <listener>
      class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-   class>
    </listener>

    <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/pages/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>


     <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-   value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is servlet-context.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

      <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
     infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
      up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
        <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

             <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp          resources 
                  in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
          <beans:bean
     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
     </beans:bean>

      <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestDB" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="pankaj" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="pankaj123" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
     <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Person</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop  key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="personDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.PersonDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="personService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.PersonServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <context:annotation-config />
<!--    <context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring, com.journaldev.spring.dao, com.journaldev.spring.model, com.journaldev.spring.service" />  -->

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

Comment: you must add your controller class code.

Comment: i tried all the results that I found on your duplicate pages and none of them give me the result. Therefore I created my own question which I have right to do to get an answer to learn, justify and make others learn

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev" />
```

Comment: WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCHibernate/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

Answer (score -1):

Controller Class Code :

```
package com.journaldev.spring;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller; 
import org.springframework.ui.Model; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import com.journaldev.spring.model.Person; 
import com.journaldev.spring.service.PersonService;

@Controller
public class PersonController {

    private PersonService personService;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "personService")
    public void setPersonService(PersonService ps) {
        this.personService = ps;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listPersons(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
        model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
        return "person";
    }

    // For add and update person both
    @RequestMapping(value= "/person/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person p) {

        if (p.getId() == 0) {
            //new person, add it
            this.personService.addPerson(p);
        } else {
            //existing person, call update
            this.personService.updatePerson(p);
        }

        return "redirect:/persons"; 
    }

    @RequestMapping("/remove/{id}")
    public String removePerson(@PathVariable("id") int id) {

        this.personService.removePerson(id);
        return "redirect:/persons";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String editPerson(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("person", this.personService.getPersonById(id));
        model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
        return "person";
    }
}
```